# How to create a notification like word of the day from a dictionary app?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am currently to create an app that support for iOS 8 and above. In my app, I want to do a daily notification like 'word of the day'. So I tried localNotification, for iOS 8-9 are using UILocalNotification whereas ios10 is using NSNotificationcenter. But I am stuck right now because I tried to pass in the variable in alertBody. it is printing empty, because the word of the day I got it from url session request. so I'm wondering, how should I do that? Please help!

Comment: Please share code for better understanding

Comment: If without code, can u briefly explain the concept ? Basically, in order to get the word of the day from my server, I need to use URLrequest to get the json and put it into my object. My question is how am I going to do it for every morning 10am to get word of the day from background even if I don't open my app. Do u have any idea?

Comment: You can use Local notifications to get daily notifications.

Comment: I tried using local but only if I able to make the URLrequest to get the word of the day then only can pass the variable to the notification. Problem is what if the user doesnt open the app in order to make the URLrequest to get the word of the day from my server? How am I trigger the URLrequest?

Comment: Use silent notification to awake your app and perform some background tasks and hit service. But needs to be done from server side, similar to remote notification. Silent notifications are not shown in notification tray and they perform task without user interaction.

Comment: Ahhh, so many setups. The server side is using php. So how am I going to implement the remote notification?

Comment: @NupurGupta, thanks for the guidance to setup the local notification. However, thats not what I want. I want the app update itself for the word of the day daily at specific time even I didn't open the apps. So hows the implementation? is it using silent notification to awake my app, and use background fetch to do urlRequest so that I can get the word from the server and send the notification via local or remote?

Comment: Without user interaction its not possible to update or get data from server on daily basis. You need to user either push notifications from server or silent notification to awake the app and perform certain task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Local notifications to get daily notifications.

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = date
notification.alertBody = "Alert!"
notification.alertAction = "open"
notification.hasAction = true
notification.userInfo = ["UUID": "reminderID" ]
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

With KCFCalenderUnitDay your notification will be fired each day but as you mentioned you need to get response for each day from server, user need to click the notification. Without clicking or user interaction this method is not called. In this method you can call your service and set local notification again.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

let state : UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
if (state == .Inactive || state == .Background) {
    // go to screen relevant to Notification content
} else {
    // App is in UIApplicationStateActive (running in foreground)
}
}
```

Set date to 9.00am

```
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
    let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)!
    cal.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")!
    let newDate: NSDate = cal.dateBySettingHour(9, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions())!
```

Adding number of days

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dayComponent.day = 1;

NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];


//Swift
var tenDaysfromNow: Date {
   return (Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: 10, to: Date(), options: [])!
}
```

Comment: for the function that u provided to me, Is it related to push notification? because I'm more into swift. don't really know obj c..

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for your help. Appreciated! Btw, do u have the correct way to set the time daily at 9am? I tried so many ways. doesnt work what I wanted.

Comment: @Andrew I have updated the code, please check. You can change TimeZone according to your requirement.

Comment: let date: NSDate = NSDate()
            let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.ISO8601)!
            cal.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
            let newDate: NSDate = cal.date(bySettingHour: 9, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options())! as NSDate

above is what I modified required by swift 3.0. when I print the newDate, what I got is 2017-09-28 01:00:00 +0000, whereas my current time now is 2017-09-28 16:36:41.214. Is it correct? but I want tmr morning 9am. which is not correct for the time....

Comment: System time zone doesn't work well. You need to provide time zone explicitly. For any date other than today use dateByAdding method. Please check my updated code.

Comment: provide time zone explicitly, for my case which is NSTimeZone(name: "UTC+8")! ?? hmmm, do u have swift version?